# Memory utilization of an JNLP application

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I understand that an JNLP application utilizes resources that are hosted on a remote web server, but what about the memory utilization by the client application running on the local machine?

We need a JVM to run JNLP applications on both sides, but where does this configuration from the JNLP file is applied to ?

j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="XXXm" max-heap-size="XXXm"

Please help me understand the heap usage of a JNLP application. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm dense but what is it you don't understand?  What exactly is your question

Comment: simply put, where is the memory allocated to a JNLP application? on the client machine or on the server where the application is hosted. or both ?

Answer (score 0):

The JNLP file is used to launch a Java application on the client machine that download it. You do not need JNLP file to run a Java application on the server. As per [Java Web Start Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/overview.html#jws) docs the JNLP is a distribution mechanism:

> When a user clicks on a link that points to a special launch file (JNLP file), it causes the browser to launch Java Web Start, which then automatically downloads, caches, and prompts the user to run the given Java Technology-based application.

The `initial-heap-size` and `max-heap-size` parameters are applied to JVM running on the client machine.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I too had similar understanding till I encountered a scenario where the client would be allocated a heap size more than the amount of physical RAM available on the client system. for example, I have executed a JNLP application with 8gb heap on a laptop client with 4gb RAM, how does that work ?

Comment: JVM will fail to start if there is not enough virtual memory. In most cases, although this OS specific, RAM + Swap File size must be smaller than Java heap.